# How to debug an Dalvik executable on Android with GDB?

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, gdb, gdbserver

I want to debug an android application using GDB, I do not have the source code and I am used to GDB. Would anyone know how to do that? It seems I would need to attach to the process of the application and use gdbserver but I have not really found a good tutorial on how to do that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There might not be step-by-step tutorials, but people have been using a gdbserver to debug JNI apps. Check the following links:

http://honeypod.blogspot.com/2008/01/debug-native-application-for-android.html

http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/09/23/hello-gdbserver-a-debuggable-jni-example-for-android/

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/android_gdb_debugging.pdf

http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Debugging#GDB_.28the_GNU_Debugger.29

Comment: I want to debug a Dalvik executable though, but thanks for the answer (I just changed the title).

Comment: @Bookix try the omappedia method (last link)